# Replicate Pylance analysis in Pyright

Tags: pylance, pyright

I've configured my VS Code project to use the Pylance extension. I know that Pylance is using Pyright internally.

We have a "no-warning" policy. I want to enforce this by running Pyright (in pre-commit and in the CI pipeline). Since Pyright is used internally by Pylance, I figured I should be able to run an equivalent analysis with a standalone Pyright.

My problem is that I don't know how to replicate the Pylance analysis in Pyright. They seem to disagree even if I use the same value for the `typeCheckingMode` parameter (i.e. `strict`).

For this code:

```
from typing import Any

a: str = 12345

b: dict[str, Any] = {}
c = b.get("a", {}).get("b", [])
```

Pylance only spots the first problem:

```
Expression of type "Literal[12345]" cannot be assigned to declared type "str"
  "Literal[12345]" is incompatible with "str"
```

However, running Pyright on the command-line, I get an additional error:

```
test.py
  test.py:3:10 - error: Expression of type "Literal[12345]" cannot be assigned to declared type "str"
    "Literal[12345]" is incompatible with "str" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
  test.py:6:1 - error: Type of "c" is partially unknown
    Type of "c" is "Any | list[Unknown]" (reportUnknownVariableType)
```

2 errors, 0 warnings, 0 informations

I'm wondering:

- Am I missing a Pyright parameter?
- Is it due to a mismatch between my Pyright version and the one embedded in Pylance?
- Is this a bug in Pylance?

**But the real question is: how can I validate, outside of VS Code, that we don't have any type error in the code that are reported by Pylance?**